# Images containing chart are not repainted after ajax load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've a page containing dataTable.NET and two images which contain charts rendered by controller. If I render a complete page first time, everything is OK.

But when I handle row click event on dataTable and trying to generate another charts depending on row Id, the images are not repainted, but if I inspect network traffic in browser, there is HTTP result 200 and mouse over icon in Firefox's log entry shows an image with the new content.

Here is my code to reaload images. If I debug my controller and/or trying debug view using alert dialogs in ajax load callback, everythink seems work properly except the images are not repainted and page shows images loaded first time when complete page has been loaded.

Please, could anybody push me forward and point out what I'm missing and/or doing wrong way?

Thanks, pf

```js
      $('#cashnode-datastatus-table-id').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {

        $('#cashnode-datastatus-table-id tbody tr').removeClass('selected');

        var row = $(this);
        row.addClass('selected');
        var data = CashNodeDataStatusTable.fnGetData(row);

        var url = '/Data/DataStatus/NodeAmountStatusChart?Id=' + data.DT_RowId;
        $("img#NodeAmountStatusChart").load(url);
        url = '/Data/DataStatus/NodeCountStatusChart?Id=' + data.DT_RowId;
        $("img#NodeCountStatusChart").load(url);

      });
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to load? If it's another image, why don't you just change `src` property?

Comment: Because I'm not a client side programmer and my experience with such stuff is a minimal. Setting src attribute works perfectly. If you are interested for reputation points and you'll provide your comment as the answer, I'll be pleased to accept it. Thank you, pf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery load function is used to load html content, which doesn't make much sense for img tags. To change images it is enough to set their source: `$('#myImg').prop('src','new/url');`.

Glad it helped :)